# Parts of HTML and CSS lost after pushing to AWS

Tags: html, css, amazon-web-services

I made a portfolio site for myself which looks fine when launched locally. I pushed it up to AWS and many random pieces of it, such as just the bg color of the body, have been lost. Any clue as to how I can fix this? I used Bootstrap, HTML, and CSS. Thank you.

EDIT: Actually, I think I'm having some weird shadowing issues as I'm trying to replace the portfolio site I had previously and many of the names are the same.

Comment: I would clear your browser cache and see if you are still having an issue - I don't think this has anything to do with AWS in particular.

Comment: What service are you pushing your portfoilio site to? For example, EC2/S3?